# 2d array reading issue javascript

Tags: javascript, arrays, multidimensional-array, conways-game-of-life

I'm trying to write conway's game of life in javascript.

The rules are:

1. If a dead pixel is surrounded by exactly three alive pixels it will come alive.
2. If an alive pixel is surrounded by less than two or more than three alive pixels it will die.

I've programmed these rules into a 2d array, however, sometimes when there is a dead pixel surrounded by less than three alive pixels it will come alive and sometimes pixels that should die will stay alive.

Mirrored objects, within the rules, should output the same but mirrored result and with my code it is inconsistent. That leads me to believe there is an error with the code checking the soundings and not the code checking the number of alive pixels (counter) around the given pixel. I cannot, however, find an error here. Maybe I'm just too tired and missing something really obvious. I'm sure there's a much better way to do it but this code should work, shouldn't it?

Please excuse the strange formatting, I was just trying to make it as clear for myself as I could to ensure that it is checking all eight pixels around itself correctly.

```
for (var x = 0; x < xPixels; x++) {
    for(var y = 0; y < yPixels; y++){
        counter = 0;
        if(y+1<yPixels){                                                //not below screen
            if(x-1>=0){         if(pixels[x-1][y+1])    {counter++;}}       //bottom left
                                if(pixels[x+0][y+1])    {counter++;}        //bottom middle
            if(x+1<xPixels){    if(pixels[x+1][y+1])    {counter++;}}       //bottom right
        }                                                               //in-line
            if(x-1>=0){         if(pixels[x-1][y+0])    {counter++;}}       //left
            if(x+1<xPixels){    if(pixels[x+1][y+0])    {counter++;}}       //right
        if (y-1>=0){                                                    //not above screen
            if(x-1>=0){         if(pixels[x-1][y-1])    {counter++;}}       //top left
                                if(pixels[x+0][y-1])    {counter++;}        //top middle
            if(x+1<xPixels){    if(pixels[x+1][y-1])    {counter++;}}       //top right
        }

        if (pixels[x][y]){                  //alive
            if(counter<2 || counter>3) {
                newPixels[x][y]=false;      //dies
            } else {
                newPixels[x][y]=true;       //stays alive
            }
        } else {                            //dead
            if(counter==3){ 
                newPixels[x][y]=true;       //born
            } else {                        
                newPixels[x][y]=false;      //stays dead
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: change for (var x = 0; x < xPixels; x++) {
    for(var y = 0; y < yPixels; y++) to for (var x = 0; x < xPixels.length; x++) {
    for(var y = 0; y < yPixels.length; y++)

Comment: Same error just flipped 90 degrees. werid